Attached XREF in Civil 3D not show up on the aerial map
I am trying to compile multiple DWG files in Civil 3D. I defined the coordinate system that is consistent with all my files, and then I went to attach my files as an XREF. When they import and I turn on the Aerial map, the data is displayed in a completely different space, not even on the map. I check the original files and they all show up in the correct space on the map there. I tried researching why and general answer I got had to do with the base point, but I tried fixing it and nothing changed. Also, I made sure the scale was the same in both drawings. Any idea on how I can fix this issue from happening?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Your Question is sparse on details that would be needed to reproduce your issue. Please [Edit] the Question.

Using command UNITS, set "Insertion scale" to match whatever units your XRef is using.
